# How to extract text from every row in a dictionary like column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have been trying this for way to long and can't seem to figure out a concise way to extract the browser from the string.  It is a column in a df so it needs to iterate over all the rows

The column looks like this

```
0        [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]
1        [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '34.0.1847.137'}]
2         [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '29.0.1547.76'}]
3        [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '33.0.1750.154'}]
4        [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]
```

The column is called browser.

I have tried the following.

```
df_agent_info['browser'].str.split("\[\{\'[a\-z]\'")
```

and other worse examples.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are the elements of your column actual list-of-dicts or string-representations of lists-of-dicts? i.e. what is `type(df_agent_info.loc[0, 'browser'])`

Comment: @AlbertoHanna  thanks for the quick response.  The code you gave gives the following error. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it is a string.  I was getting integer errors before I changed the type

Comment: @AlbertoHanna KeyError: 0

Comment: @d3hero23, added another solution to it, one liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<='name': ')[\w ]+"

def match(x):
    if re.findall(pattern, x):
        return re.findall(pattern, x)[0]

df['browser'].apply(match)
```

`(?<='name': ')` is a *positive lookbehind*: it looks for matches that follow in this case `'name': '`

Comment: here is what that returned
  line 1, in <lambda>
    test=df_agent_info['browser'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(pattern, x)[0])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: there are some missing rows, but shouldnt i just return NA?

Comment: I changed it so it will return none if it can't match anything.

Comment: Also, added an space into the regex so it can match names with more than one word (like "Internet Explorer"

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
                                            browser
0  [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]
1  [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '34.0.1847.137'}]
2   [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '29.0.1547.76'}]
3  [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '33.0.1750.154'}]
4  [{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]
```

Let's evaluate them as python:

```
df.browser = df.browser.apply(eval)
```

Now we can extract it easily:

```
df.browser = df.browser.str[0].str.get('name')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  browser
0  Chrome
1  Chrome
2  Chrome
3  Chrome
4  Chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the strings to lists containing a dict using the built-in `ast.literal_eval` (it is safer than using `eval`), and then get the 'name' value of each dictionary using `list_dict[0]['name']`. Apply this logic to each string value of the `browser` column using `Series.apply`.

Putting all together:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df_agent_info = pd.DataFrame({
    'browser': ["[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '34.0.1847.137'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '29.0.1547.76'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '33.0.1750.154'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]"]
})

df_agent_info['browser'] = df_agent_info['browser'].apply(lambda s: ast.literal_eval(s)[0]['name'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df_agent_info['browser']

0    Chrome
1    Chrome
2    Chrome
3    Chrome
4    Chrome
Name: browser, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I got this error.  I converted the column to a string again and it still gave back that error again...AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!...

Comment: @d3hero23 I am not using the `str` accessor, are you sure you are running the same code as in my solution?

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do it, One liner

using regex groups to match for content b/w the astrophes, by using regex groups

```
df['browser'].str.extract(r'(:\s).?([\w\s]*)')[1].str.strip()
```

```
0    Internet Explore
1              Chrome
2              Chrome
3              Chrome
4              Chrome
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'browser': ["[{'name': 'Internet Explore', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '34.0.1847.137'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '29.0.1547.76'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '33.0.1750.154'}]",
                "[{'name': 'Chrome', 'version': '36.0.1985.143'}]"]
})
```

[image]

Comment: df I used is also in the answer, and result was based on it. Did you try the df from this answer?

Comment: also added the screenshot of my notebook